# Javascript full height intro section with auto padding chrome bug, not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I tried to achieve a full-height intro section with some basic javascript markup.

In more detail:
I got a parent DIV element which acts as a wrapper and should adapt to the full viewport height. Due to some mobile incompatibility, the css "height: 100vh" is not working. So I stuck to this code. It worked perfect a while ago. I did not change anything, suddenly it stopped working in chrome overnight?! The height do not get calculated properly.

I attached you my code and some screenshots of the case.

I am certain you can help me out.
Thank you in advance
[Working sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuA7A.jpg)
[Chrome bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkOnr.jpg)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

'use strict';

setInterval( function() {

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    var containerHeight = $("#intro-wrapper > .inner").height();

    var navHeight = $("header#main").outerHeight(true);

    var border = 20;

    var padTop = windowHeight - 20 - (containerHeight+navHeight);

    $("#intro-wrapper > .inner").css ({

        'padding-top': Math.round(padTop / 2) + 'px',
        'padding-bottom': ((padTop / 2)- border) + 'px',
        'margin-bottom': border + 'px'
    });

}, 0);
});
```

Comment: You are only setting padding and margin propertys at the div element. Why you do not simple set the height and width of the element?

Comment: I choosed this to simple vertically center the "welcome-div" including some content, but I give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `height:100vh;` in css for full height.

Comment: already tried but in the mobile version it don't adapt to the full height.